# dynamic legend for fusion table map

Tags: google-fusion-tables, legend

I have a modified sample of fusion table map and its code is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fusion Tables Layer Example: Dynamic styles and templates</title>
    <style>
    body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }
    #map-canvas { height: 660px; width: 100%; }
    #map-canvas img { max-width: none; }
    #visualization { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
    #legend1 { width: 200px; background: #FFF;padding: 10px; margin: 5px;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;border: 1px solid black;}
    .color {border: 1px solid;height: 12px;width: 15px; margin-right: 3px;float: left;}
    .red {background: #C00;}
    .blue {background: #06C;}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4, -122.1),
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: 'Address',
            from: '15UY2pgiz8sRkq37p2TaJd64U7M_2HDVqHT3Quw'
          },
          map: map,
          styleId: 1,
          templateId: 1
        });
        var legend1 = document.createElement('div');
        legend1.id = 'legend1';
        var content1 = [];
        content1.push('<p><div class="color red"></div>Red markers</p>');
        legend1.innerHTML = content1.join('');
        legend1.index = 1;
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend1);   
        var legend2 = document.createElement('div');
        legend2.id = 'legend1';
        var content2 = [];
        content2.push('<p><div class="color blue"></div>Blue markers</p>');
        legend2.innerHTML = content2.join('');
        legend2.index = 1;
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend2);
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('style'),
            'change', function() {
              var selectedStyle = this.value;
              layer.set('styleId', selectedStyle);
              var selectedTemplate = this.value;
              layer.set('templateId', selectedTemplate);
        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div>
      <label>Select style:</label>
      <select id="style">
        <option value="1">Red</option>
        <option value="2">Blue</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I add dynamic legend to this map so that when selecting blue markers, the legend should show only a blue marker with its name and when selecting red markers it will show the red marker icon in legend.

Comment: The color of a marker is not enough information. Your example only changes the color of each marker, may I assume that you want to have marker-colors based on the value of a column(regarding to the used table I would guess on the `delivery`-column) and want to filter the markers based on this column?

Comment: I require a legend in right bottom corner of the map which shows which style type is selected. ie, if selected blue marker, it should show the blue marker icon and so on.

Comment: There are only blue markers when you select the blue markers from the dropdown, there is no condition to show specific markers(you did not specify any where-clause), so there isn't any dynamic condition to apply a dynamic legend.

Comment: @Dr.Molle- Please see the edited code above in which there is two legends. But I stuck how to use it inside the event.listener function. ie, for selection of option 1 the first legend should show and vice versa.

Comment: find the above code sample in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/565qZ/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must clear the controls(remove all legends) and then add the  desired legend again.

right **before**

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('style')[...]
```

add this code:

```
//we need a copy of all legends(nodes), 
//otherwise they wouldn't be accessible when they have been removed
var clonedArray = map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM]
                       .getArray().slice();

//observe changes of the styleId
google.maps.event.addListener(layer,'styleid_changed',function(){
    //clear the controls
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].clear();
    //add the desired control
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM]
            .push(clonedArray[this.get('styleId')-1])
});

//trigger the event to initially have only the legend 
//based on the selected style   
google.maps.event.trigger(layer,'styleid_changed');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/t3nY6/